# Is element collection of Entities an association in JPA?

Tags: jpa, collections, associations

IN JPA, what is an association? it is not well defined. ManyToMany, OneToMany, OneToOne and ManyToOne are associations between two entities.

How about element collection (element type is Entity)? For example,

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @ElementCollection
    private List<Address> addresses;
}

@Entity
public class Address {

}
```

Is the attribute(addresses) an association?

Comment: From [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html): Specifies a collection of instances of a **basic type** or **embeddable class** (emphasis mine). So **not** a collection of entities.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/MapKeyJoinColumn.html, example 2. ElementCollection: Map key can be entity.